# What is this compilation error in perl? I do not see a syntax problem

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(TEST, "leet.txt") or die "Can't open leet.txt: $!\n";
while(my $line = <TEST>) {
    if($line =~ tr/34/ea/)
        print <<EOF;
$line
EOF
}
```

It produces this:
    syntax error at ./practice.pl line 11, near ")
                print"
    Execution of ./practice.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enclose the `if` commands in a `{ }` block, even when it has just one command. Unlike other languages, in Perl, this is not optional.

```
    if($line =~ tr/34/ea/) {
        print <<EOF;
$line
EOF
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just skipped pasting two "}" at the end. Then add "{":

if($line =~ tr/34/ea/) **{**

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally run a single statement place the conditional after the statement.  For example, these two statements have the same behavior:

```
if ($bar) { print "foo!\n"; }
print "foo!\n" if ($bar);
```

In the case of your code you could write it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(TEST, "leet.txt") or die "Can't open leet.txt: $!\n";
while(my $line = <TEST>) {
        print <<EOF if ($line =~ tr/34/ea/);
$line
EOF
}
close TEST;
```